# How to get more information when I receive "Failed to start quarkus: java.util.NoSuchElementException"?

Tags: quarkus

After having updated Quarkus version from 2.16.0.FINAL to 2.16.1.Final I get following trace when I start in DEV mode:

```
ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.NameIterator.prevPos(NameIterator.java:157)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.NameIterator.getPreviousStart(NameIterator.java:217)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.NameIterator.previous(NameIterator.java:327)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.matching.ConfigPatternMap.match(ConfigPatternMap.java:46)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.BuildTimeConfigurationReader$ReadOperation.run(BuildTimeConfigurationReader.java:448)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.BuildTimeConfigurationReader.lambda$readConfiguration$0(BuildTimeConfigurationReader.java:322)
        at io.smallrye.config.SecretKeys.doUnlocked(SecretKeys.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.BuildTimeConfigurationReader.readConfiguration(BuildTimeConfigurationReader.java:322)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader.loadStepsFrom(ExtensionLoader.java:195)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:107)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:331)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:252)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:60)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:86)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:447)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:59)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:149)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:104)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:131)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:62)
```

What could I do to find out which element is missing?

I think it has to do something with configuration values but I have no idea which is missing.

I already tried to start with DEBUG log level but there's also no hint what's missing.

pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>baz</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.37</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.16.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <keycloak.version>17.0.1</keycloak.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-oidc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-oidc-token-propagation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hal</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-authorization</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

When I use `<quarkus.platform.version>2.16.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>` I get the error mentioned above.

When I use `<quarkus.platform.version>2.16.0.Final</quarkus.platform.version>` everything works fine.

Comment: Is there no more info in the logs?

Comment: is it possible to share the `pom.xml` file(after removing sensitive information).

Comment: No more infos in the logs. I also enabled debug mode which gives tons of output but I did not find any hint.